# alter password reset url

Tags: 7, users

I'm trying to alter the password reset link (user/password) to my own language specific URL, but I can't find how I can do this.

How can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal has different way to understand which language should be used to show the current page. By default, Drupal shows the pages in the language set in admin/config/regional/language; other detection methods are disabled. (See the settings on admin/config/regional/language/configure.)

> [image]

If you want to use a different language, and since you are asking for a page that is normally used from anonymous users, you would need to enable the *Browser* method that will select the language for the pages basing on the browser settings and the HTTP headers the browser uses when seeing a page.
The *Session* method uses a session variable (which means the user already visited one of the pages on your site), or a request parameter; it could be the right method if you know the user already visited your site at least one, with cookies enabled for your site.

Answer (score 0):

Render **user_pass** form in your custom url.
**drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_pass'));**

OR

In template.php

```
function mymodule_theme(){
// custom user-password.tpl.php
    $items['user_pass'] = array(
        'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
        'render element' => 'form',
        'template' => 'templates/user-pass',
    );
    return $items;
}
```

In user-pass.tpl.php:

```
php global $base_url; 


div class="forgotPassword"
Forgot Password

php
    print drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);
    print drupal_render($form['form_id']);
    print drupal_render($form['name']);
    print drupal_render($form['actions']);
?
/div
```